# Run local script on remote server with sudo privileges

Tags: bash, ssh, sudo

On Ubuntu 16.04, using VS Code, I want to run a local script on a remote server with `sudo` privileges.

Here is `local.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo $(ifconfig | grep -Eo "inet addr:([0-9]\.?)*")
echo $(whoami)
echo "$1"
```

Here is one version of the `test.sh` script that I use to run `local.sh` remotely:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
remote="example.com"
user="username"
password="remote_password"
ssh "$user@$remote" "bash -s" < ./local.sh "'argument 1'"
```

This works fine. Here is the output, as expected:

```
$ ./test.sh 
inet addr:123.45.67.89 inet addr:127.0.0.1
username
argument 1
```

The first IP address is indeed the IP address of the server.

However, I want to run `local.sh` with `sudo` on the remote server. If I replace the last line with the following line, access is blocked:

```
ssh -tt "$user@$remote" "echo $password | sudo bash -s" < ./local.sh "'argument 1'"
```

Output:

```
$ ./test.sh 
[sudo] password for username: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for username:
```

If I type a password after the second prompt, the characters appear in the Terminal, and when I press Enter, nothing happens, so I use ^C to cancel.

If I only use `-t` as the flag to `ssh`, I get the output:

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

If I use no flags at all, I get:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Other solutions that I have seen proposed have not been more successful. Any insights into what I should do will be most welcome.

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391796/pipe-password-to-sudo-and-other-data-to-sudoed-command

Comment: @guiverc This question is not 16.04 specific, so I think there's no need to mention that 16.04 is not supported anymore.

Comment: @raj, given I'm involved with Ubuntu News; I think that reminding people that their system is EOL & packages are no longer maintained security wise, is beneficial. Regardless the on-topic rules state "*Support for versions for Ubuntu releases past their "End of Standard Support" or "End of Life" dates (whichever is earlier) — unless the question is asking how to upgrade to a supported release*" which applies here don't you think?  I don't see this question to be about moving to a supported release...

Comment: ["Useless echo? Instead of 'echo $(cmd)' just use cmd"](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2005)

Comment: `sudo` will not accept a password on stdin. Use `expect` or `sshpass`

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want to do, Try `expect`

And to keep it secure, try to encrypt your files

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/expect.1.html

Answer (score 0):

Install `expect` and use the following script (not tested, there may be bugs):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set remote "example.com"
set user "username"
set password "remote_password"
spawn ssh -l $user $remote
expect "$ "
send "sudo bash -s < ./local.sh 'argument 1'\r"
expect "password for $user:"
send "$password\r"
expect "$ "
send "exit\r"
```

`expect` simulates an interactive session. The `spawn` command runs `ssh -l $user $remote` and the following commands interact with it. The `expect` command waits until the specified text appears in the output, and then `send` command sends the text to the remote host. You can find more at the link specified in the other answer.

Comment: Many thanks for the sample script. After the script logs on to the remote server, the file `local.sh` is no longer visible, since it is on the local machine.

Comment: @JamesNewton You intended to run a script that is on a local machine on a remote one? That's not possible. Instead, put explicitly all the commands you want to run on the remote machine into `send` statements in the above script. Or just copy the `local.sh` file to the remote machine first using `scp` and then run it there.